# Is composition of two transitive relations transitive? If not, can you give me a counterexample?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let $S$ and $R$ be transitive relations on set $A$. Is $S∘R$ also transitive?

Comment: What are your thoughts? And how are the domains/codomains of $S$ and $R$ related?

Comment: Both are on the same set. It doesn't seem to be true for general case but I can't find the counterexample.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$S=\{(2,3),(4,5)\}$ and $R=\{(1,2),(3,4)\}$ is a counterexample. They're both transitive, but $S\circ R=\{(1,3),(3,5)\}$ is not.

Comment: You can easily make $S$ and $R$ equivalence relations, with equivalence classes $\{\{1\},\{2,3\},\{4,5\}\}$ and $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5\}\}$ respectively, by adding in more ordered pairs to each. The example would still work.

Comment: Thanks. My problem was I was thinking in terms of "smaller-than", equality or being a subset.

Comment: @dddwww This has a geometric interpretation of five points arranged in a staircase fashion, with $aSb$ meaning $a$ is in the same row as $b$ but in a higher column, and $aRb$ meaning $a$ is in the same column as $b$ but in a higher row.

Comment: Like this:$\begin{matrix}&&1\\&3&2\\5&4&\end{matrix}$ @dddwww

Comment: I got the order the right way around. The codomain of $R$ is the domain of $S$, as required. Unfortunately, the standard composition notation is confusing and backwards from what it should be. (I've seen $R\mathbin{\mathbf ;}S$ used to mean composition the other way, e.g., $S\circ R$. In LaTeX (not MathJax), you can use `\usepackage{stmaryrd}` and then `\fatsemi` to get a version that looks nicer.)